# Prometheus endpoint of all available metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql

I was curious concerning the workings of Prometheus. Using the Prometheus interface I am able to see a drop-down list which I assume contains all available metrics. However, I am not able to access the metrics endpoint which lists all of the scraped metrics.  The `http://targethost:9090/metrics` endpoint only displays the metrics concerning the Prometheus server itself. Is it possible to access a similar endpoint which lists all available metrics. I could perform a query based on `{__name__=~".+"}` but I would prefer to avoid this option.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The endpoint for that is http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/__name__/values

[API Reference](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#getting-label-names)

Comment: Show all available metrics, use `__name__`  instead: http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/__name__/values

Comment: The http://localhost:9090/api/v1/metadata api endpoint also shows HELP description.
[API reference](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-metric-metadata)

Answer (score 3):

Prometheus provides [/federate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) API, which can be used for returning all the scraped metrics. For example, the following [curl](https://curl.se/) query returns all the metrics in Prometheus text exposition format (e.g. in the same format as `/metrics` output), which were scraped recently:

```sh
curl -G http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/federate -d 'match[]={__name__!=""}'
```

P.S. [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) supports additional `start` and `end` query args, which can be used for returning metrics scraped at a specific time range - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#federation).